# Como usar o count corretamente

Tags: sql

Usei essa query para encontrar os jobs que não se relacionam:

```
SELECT *FROM D_WRKDB.TB_RDMP_CTRLM_JOB CTJ
LEFT JOIN D_WRKDB.TB_RDMP_CTRLMJOB_HAS_WORKFLOW CTW
    ON CTW.ID_CTRLM_JOB = CTJ.ID_CTRLM_JOB
    WHERE CTW.ID_CTRLM_JOB IS NULL
```

Agora preciso usar um count na coluna `MEMNAME` que está na tabela `TB_RDMP_CTRLM_JOB`.

Mas não estou conseguindo.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: E qual foi a SQL que tentou fazer? Qual foi o resultado?

Comment: Você quer contar quantas ocorrências existem para cada valor de MEMNAME? Algo do tipo: ,,, COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY MEMNAME?

Comment: Que problema você encontrou? deu algum erro?

Comment: Consegui resolver usando GROUP BY ! OBRIGADO PELA AJUDA PESSOAL!